# boost:scoped_ptr to boost::ptr_vector without releasing resource

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

Disclaimer : This is C++03. My apologies for not making that clear before. Also auto_ptr is out because of company guidelines.

Example code:

```
void foo(boost::ptr_vector<MyType>& iPtrVector)
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<MyType> aScopedPtr = new MyType();
    // lots of logic here

    if (condition)
        iPtrVector.push_back(*aScopedPtr);
} // eek! Resource is freed, but maybe referenced in iPtrVector now!
```

My issue with this is that the resource will be deleted when the scoped pointer goes out of scope, but actually I want the resource to be maintained in the ptr_vector *if* my condition is true. My approach would be to *revoke ownership* from the scoped_ptr if I decided I needed to hold it in the ptr vector. However, scoped_ptr doesn't permit this.

Thus I've built a simple class to handle it for me :

```
template <class T>
struct CustomScopedPointer
{
    CustomScopedPointer() : _targetPtr(NULL) { }
    ~CustomScopedPointer() { delete _targetPtr; }
    T* _targetPtr;

    // calling this with a null ptr will ensure the resource 
    // isn't deleted at dtor time
    CustomScopedPointer& operator=(T* rhs)
    {
        _targetPtr = rhs;
        return *this;
    }

};
```

Is there a way to do this without defining my own class, however? It seems overkill for a particular specific circumstance, and I was very surprised to find that there is no way to prevent a smart pointer from deleting its managed resource - even a reset or reassignment first frees the original resource.

(As for why I'm forced to handle it like this, it's because of *business* reasons. Suffice to say that the resource must be freed in case of exception, etc, but equally cannot be inside the ptr_vector except in some circumstances)

Comment: Not a very clean solution, but you could have a `ptr_vector<scoped_ptr<T>>`. When you need to add to the vector, `push_back` an empty `scoped_ptr<T>` and then `swap` the last element in the vector with the `scoped_ptr` that you want to take ownership from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
auto aScopedPtr = make_unique<MyType>();
// lots of logic here

if (condition)
    iPtrVector.push_back(aScopedPtr.release());
```

You can search around for an implementation of `make_unique` to copy and paste. You can use:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyType> aScopePtr{ new MyType() };
```

If you really have to, but strongly prefer `make_unique`.

---

If you can't use C++11 features, you can do the same with `std::auto_ptr`:

```
std::auto_ptr<MyType> aScopePtr{ new MyType() };
```

Just be aware it's deprecated and has pitfalls.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I cannot use unique_ptr due to us being limited to C++03. I will update the question. I'm also not permitted to use auto_ptr because of business rules in the company :( Upvoted anyway, because your answer is absolutely correct if my hands weren't tied!

Comment: @MikeB: Added a C++03 alternative.

Comment: unique_ptr can be used in C++03. There's Howard Hinnant's backport for example which I'm using with reasonable degree of success.